# What is $\sinh(x)$? And $i\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, euler-mascheroni-constant

I've been looking around the internet for a way to solve $\sin(i)$, and I found something about $\sinh(x)$

I furthered my search and found something about $\sinh(x)= \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$. When I tried plugging in $i\pi=x$, I got two very separate answers: 
$$\sinh(i\pi) = 1.2246468 \times 10^{-16}i,$$ but when I plug $i\pi$ into the other, I get $0$. So if there is some rule law or theorem I'm missing, I'd appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Pleas use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin$ and $\sinh$ are different functions,
$$\sin(x)=\frac{\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)}{2i},\quad\sinh(x)=\frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2}.$$

They are connected by the relation $$\sinh(x)=-i\sin(ix).$$

Comment: Yes I am aware I was just stating how I got super curious about sinh but why do I get different answers for sinh(i*pi) and (e^(i*pi) - e^(-i*pi))/2?

Comment: They aren't different. $10^{-16}$ is extremely small, and indicates a tiny numerical error on the part of the calculator.

Comment: They should be equal because $\sinh(i\pi)=0$, and $\exp(i\pi)-\exp(-i\pi)=0$. The last is true because $\exp(-i\pi)=\exp(-i\pi+2\pi i)=\exp(\pi i)$.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, so I over looked the negative when I was doing this fast. Thank u all for so much help, I see it now. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Computer calculations are not exact, because a real number cannot be specified with infinite precision using only a finite number of bits. The common double precision floating point arithmetic will only represent numbers to within approximately $10^{-16}$, which is the magnitude of the difference between the two calculations.

In other words, this is a rounding error. The two expressions are exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

A famous relation states$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$from which we conclude that$$\sin x={e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\over 2i}$$also$$\sinh x={e^{x}-e^{-x}\over 2}$$therefore$$\sinh x={e^{i(-ix)}-e^{i(ix)}\over2}=i\cdot {e^{i(-ix)}-e^{i(ix)}\over2}=-i\sin -ix=i\sin ix$$so we can write$$\sinh u=i\sin iu\\\sin u=i\sinh iu$$in this case$$\sin i=-i\sinh 1$$